# Auto login and screen scrape

Tags: c#, post, authentication, screen-scraping

I'm pretty new to code but hoping someone can set me on the right path. I'm trying to setup some code which logs me into a website and then screenscrapes the data so that I can tell if the site has been updated, it's for a ticket website and I essentially want to setup to check every x minutes to see if any new tickets have been loaded up. From what I've read in previous replies I think I need to be using c# and using a POST command but, try as I might, I've not managed to make much headway. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?